# git commit exclamation results in zsh: illegal modifier:

Tags: git, zsh, commit

I'm running the latest available stable version of Zsh and am running into an error using a `!` exclamation mark in a git commit message, following conventional commit style. https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/

```
→ zsh --version
zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0)
```

And the zsh-offending commit message:

```
→ git commit -am "chore(foo)!: bar"    
zsh: illegal modifier:
```

I've tried the same command in Bash, Fish, and Hyper and all succeed without issue. So this appears to be another wonky Zsh nuance. Does anyone have a fix for zsh? I'd really like to be able to use the `-am` shorthand rather than having to go into the full `git commit` interactive editor.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`zsh` interprets the `!` as the beginning of a history expansion. Just use single quotes instead of double quotes.

```
git commit -am 'chore(foo)!: bar'
```